# How do I install bootstrap js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed the hartl rails book to install the bootstrap css files, but I believe I'm missing the javascript to go with it. Here's what the book told me to do:

1. add `bootstrap-sass` to the Gemfile: `gem 'bootstrap-sass'`
2. run bundle install
3. add the following to the css:

   ```
   @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
   @import "bootstrap";
   ```

What else do I need to do to add the javascript portion? my `application.js` right now:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails):

> Require Bootstrap Javascripts in app/assets/javascripts/application.js

So in `application.js` add:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Also, don't forget to restart the server after `bundle install`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought I responded to this but I guess not. In application.js I already have jquery and I have require bootstrap (not require bootstrap-sprockets). What does this mean?

Comment: [Read this why not to require bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/829#issuecomment-75153827). So, instead of `//= require bootstrap` use `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` and restart the server.